# Make device take power only from charger when the battery is full

Tags: charging

I made a device that is up and running (screen is on) 24/7 and connected to AC charger. After only 1 year, the batteries of these devices are dead. I don't really understand since the device is directly connected to AC, the battery should be bypassed and never been used.

I made some current measurements and I discovered that the current consumed by the device is sometimes 0 for ~1 minute. So it is obvious that the battery is working because if AC current is 0 while the screen is on, it means the battery is working.

This power management does not make any sense. Is it the expected one? Is there any hack I can do using ADB commands?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

"I don't really understand since the device is directly connected to AC, the battery should be bypassed and never been used.

If you mean li-ion battery, cycle use is recommended
since keeping it fully charged for 24/365 may shorten its life cycle as in your case.

Since you need battery as backup only, use UPS (Pb  gel battery) coming with bypass instead

Comment: This is a fairly frequent requirement, when doing DIY smart home or similar. It's easy to repurpose an old tablet/phone for a control screen, but the issue with power (and dying battery) is ever present. How do you fix it with a UPS? A tablet charge cable can be easily hidden in-wall (in-mount), but how do you hide a UPS? Finally, how would you configure the UPS to only turn on an supply power once the device battery is nearing depletion?

Comment: " how would you configure the UPS to only turn on an supply power once the device battery is nearing depletion?

Comment: " how would you configure the UPS to only turn on an supply power once the device battery is nearing depletion?

Just replace your device battery with small UPS.

Rear window car camera comes with small capacity li-ion battery back-up but when you leave your car, camera gets disconnected from charger and li-ion battery leaves fully-charged status overnight.

Use 2 batteries and a switch  to make one charged on even days and the other on odd days

Comment: Car camera? I had to go re-read the OP several times to make sure I didn't miss any references to car cameras.... or cars... nope. Sorry dude, you totally lost me there

Comment: smartphone's battery comes with charging controller built-in to prevent overcharge but a user is advised not to keep his/her smartphone connected to the charger, while making phone calls.
  
I used my Android tablet as PC with external usb mouse, 3g modem, keyboard connected and non-stop charged.

Today I develop 3D scanner with 20 usb  5Mpix cameras, sensing OTG charging pin. USB camera if connected to charger or PC switches from camera mode into charging mode, so I need to disable sensing pin with Arduino to keep camera on, when connected to PC via hub for data transfer. No easy solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I cannot change the battery type. My devices are already on production and I have no access to them. Is there any adb command I could run remotely to change the way the battery is managed?

Comment: there is a nice app for Android, called Battery Doctor
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijinshan.kbatterydoctor_en&hl=en_US

just read about the features supported

not sure if you can emulate Battery Doctor with adb commands 

http://adbshell.com/

" Healthy Charge Master
Monitor charging status and extend battery life when charging.

"❄Battery Cooler
Battery Cooler feature accurately detect phone temperature, disables heat-producing apps to cool down battery.

Comment: Hi again,

I have got such message emailed:
 Make device take power only from charger when the battery is full
"
Please do not post throwaway answers. Provide a specific solution with steps needed to achieve th...
"

See all of your inbox items:
https://stackexchange.com/users/6109220?tab=inbox 

The problem is don't have any such inbox, since link is invalid
_____
There is no easy solution to your problem since chemistry of Li-Ion cells bans charging to be 24/365 on, due to pillow syndrome.
Share more details about your device if you are looking for specific solution.